# Get negative control voltage for a AS3310 chip

Tags: voltage, negative

I'm trying to use a AS3310 chip to generate an envelope from a trigger/gate signal.

The AS3310 expects for the ADR (attack/decay/release) control voltage 0 to -5V - for the S (Sustain) 0 to +5V

I have a power supply of +12V/-12V/+5V sharing the same Ground. So where or how would I get the 0 to -5V from? Would I need to use an inverting op-amp? Is there a more simple solution?

Datasheet for AS3310: http://www.uk-electronic.de/PDF/AS3310.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an easy job for a linear, negative voltage regulator IC.

Just like there's a whole world of voltage regulators that can give you +5 V from a + 12 V source, you can get -5V from a -12V source using the right regulator.

Something like the [LM2990](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2990).

Anyways, trying to grasp this AS3310 chip: It seems like an *extreme* specific one, and I honestly don't see why you'd need a chip that needs three different potentials (Vee, Vcc, GND), multiple voltage inputs (which you'd have to accurately generate somewhere else), as well as 11 (!) external components to generate such simple waveforms. Are you sure you wouldn't be happier with just a microcontroller generating these waveforms? Considering the timescales are all significantly larger than 1 ms, every modern microcontroller would be fast enough, and you could even get away without a proper DAC unit or separate IC, simply by PWM/chopping and proper low-pass filtering.

Comment: Thanks Marcus,

The AS3310 is very specific unless you are in analog synth gear. 

Thanks for the input, LM2990 seems to do the job - on the other hand, I have still the option of using an op-amp to get the -5V from the +5V and there would be the option of using a LM7905, I guess, although I haven't experimented with it, yet.

At least I'm having now enough options to play on my breadboard and figure out, which solutions fits my need, best.

Comment: Regarding the multiple power inputs, which have to be generated (more or less accurately elsewhere) which seems to puzzle you: These are actually generated by multiple sources of a synthesizer setup. External and internal routed signals, random, clocked or sequenced. From analog and digital gear or your computer.

Comment: @m_c thanks for the feedback! yeah, but every power line you have to route to a chip is additional pain, and an additional source of noise; that's why, especially in an audio context, I'd have expected avoidance wherever possible – in this case, if your time scales are kept short, AC coupling might have been sufficient, so that technically, a single supply must have sufficed. Seems like the IC was designed in an era where it wasn't as easy as it is to day to integrate your voltage regulators on-chip.

Comment: i.e. from the functionality alone: The thing only outputs voltages between ground and positive 5V, and its inputs are between ground and positive supply only, too. There's nothing in there that would, with modern circuitry, demand a negative rail, *even with DC coupling*! Yet, you need one; that just seems like an avoidable hassle, which is why I'm so surprised.